# Session data I've set disappears after a period of inactivity

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I may be doing this the wrong way, or there may be a better way to do it..

Upon login I'm setting some session data:

```
session(['api_token' => $user->api_token]);
session(['season' => Season::find($request->season)]);
session(['centres' => Centre::where('active', 1)->get()]);
```

I call it like so...

```
session('season')->name
```

.env file:

```
SESSION_LIFETIME=9999999999
```

This works great for a while, but if there's a period of a few hours of activity (I haven't timed it exactly), then the session data I've set gets lost, I have to log out then back in to set the session data again.

**However, the user still remains logged in, I can pull Auth data perfectly fine.**

What is going on here?

Comment: check php.ini file and session.php files

Comment: is that number not outrageous? why not SESSION_LIFETIME =3000 and start with that to see if it works

Comment: you are setting the session to almost 32 years

Comment: Hi Emeka - it is a bit outrageous I suppose! But why would the Auth session that is managed by Laravel still be set?

Comment: I think I may know the cause - I didn't change the env file on my public server... woops.

Answer (score 0):

I think it turns out I didn't change the ENV session_lifetime on the public server... my bad!